# HttpResponseMessage how to set Message property

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have an asp.net web API. I have a filter attribute and OnAuthorization I am returning HttpResponseMessage as follows.

```
public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    //Check Request Start-End Period
    if (!CheckRequestTime())
    {
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage
        {
            StatusCode = (HttpStatusCode) 429,
            ReasonPhrase = "Invalid Request Time",
            Content = new StringContent("Requests are permitted between " +
                                        WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TimeStart"].ToString() +
                                        " AM and " + WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TimeEnd"].ToString() +
                                        " PM.")


        };

        actionContext.Response = response;
    }
}
```

A Client wants me to return ResponseMessageResult​ which means adding Message property to the response as follows:

```
{
    "Message": "Requests are permitted between 11:00 AM and 22:30 PM."
}
```

**UPDATE**
This solved my problem.

```
Content = new StringContent("{\"Message\":\"Requests are permitted between " +
                                                WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TimeStart"].ToString() +
                                                " AM and " + WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TimeEnd"].ToString() +
                                                " PM.\"}", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"),
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. What do you want the response body to be - plain text (as it is now) or JSON? Is your question really just "how can I create JSON from a message"?

Comment: Yes, something like this; Content = new JsonContent(new
                    {
                        Message = "Any Message" //return exception
                    })

Comment: Well if you keep using `StringContent`, the problem becomes "How do I create JSON" which has nothing to do with ASP.NET at all - you can do that various ways, including using Json.NET (Newtonsoft.Json). There are lots of tutorials for creating JSON. (You probably want to set the content type appropriately.)